# How to move a file back to the parent folder

Tags: git, git-bash

I moved a .txt file to another sub-folder in the parent folder using `git mv someName.txt NameOfFolder/someName.txt` function but I cant seem to get it back, only way I can succeed is by doing it by File Explorer. What do I use to move it to previous folder/parent folder. I'm only learning Git now as you can see.

Comment: Have you tried using `mv` with the arguments reversed, or looked at [its documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv)? (Note: `mv` isn't a Git command; it's a shell command.)

Comment: @Chris by "using mv with the arguments reversed" you mean git mv someName.txt Parentfolder/someName.txt ? If that is what you mean then yes and I got fatal error

Comment: I mean `mv NameOfFolder/someName.txt someName.txt` from the parent folder. If you want to do it from the child folder you can use `..` to represent the parent: `mv someName.txt ../someName.txt`. Since you're not renaming the file this can be shortened to `mv someName.txt ..`.

Comment: @IgorTheBoss : can you post the error message that you get when running `git mv NameOfFolder/someName.txt someName.txt` ?

Comment: @LeGEC fatal: bad source, source=hithere.txt, destination=Test/hithere.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the parent folder with `..`.

Navigate to the `NameOfFolder` and run `mv someName.txt ../someName.txt`

See example:

```
parentfolder $ mv file.txt subfolder/file.txt
parentfolder $ cd subfolder
subfolder $ ls
file.txt
subfolder $ mv file.txt ../file.txt
subfolder $ ls
// empty
subfolder $ cd ..
parentfolder $ ls
subfolder
file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a git reset if haven't made any commit after you moved the file and you made no other changes to the repository

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Or you can do

```
git mv yourfile path/to/destination
```

Comment: `git mv` won't work here. Since the file was moved outside of Git there is no `NameOfFolder/someName.txt` entry in the index.